# CCMoveTo doesn't get the updated player postition.....(iphone,cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, position, move

I'm adding an enemy like this:

```
-(void)addEnemy {
    if ([spawnedEnemies count] < 25) {
        CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"white.png"];
        float randomX = arc4random() % 480;
        float randomY = arc4random() % 320;

        sprite.position = ccp(randomX,randomY);
        [spawnedEnemies addObject:sprite];
        [self addChild:sprite];  

        [sprite runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5 position:player.position]];
    } }
```

but if my player moves the sprite still moves to the last player position...
because of that i tried this in my tick:

> -(void)tick:(ccTime)delta {
>
> ```
> for (CCSprite *sp in spawnedEnemies) {
>     [sp stopAllActions];
>     [sp runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5
> ```
>
> position:player.position]];
>       } }

but the enemies will only move if i stop moving (there just moving reallllllllyyyyyyyyy slow because every time i move it calls [sp stopAllActions]

What should I do now?

**EDIT:****EDIT:**EDIT:**EDIT:**EDIT:**EDIT:**EDIT:**EDIT:**EDIT:
Now I'm doing this and the enemies are moving to the player even if the player is moving
but there's a problem: the nearer the enemy (is to the player) the slower they are moving...
How to solve this?

```
//function to apply a velocity to a position with delta
static CGPoint applyVelocity(CGPoint velocity, CGPoint position, float delta){
    return CGPointMake(position.x + velocity.x * delta, position.y + velocity.y * delta);
}


-(void)tick:(ccTime)delta {    
    for (CCSprite *sp in spawnedEnemies) {
        CGPoint m = ccpSub(player.position, sp.position);
        sp.position = applyVelocity(m, sp.position, 1.0/60.0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have four ideas:

1. Schedule a new update selector with a lower frequency and move the enemies in that method:  `[self schedule:@selector(moveEnemies) interval:0.1];`
2. Only move the enemies when the player.position changes, maybe in your `ccTouchesMoved`-method.
3. Instead of using CCActions, set the position of the sprite directly, you need to do some vector-computations.
4. Use a physics-engine like Box2D (included in Cocos2D SDK). Then you can simply apply a force to each enemy to the direction of the player in each step.

***EDIT:***
In order to move the enemies with constant velocity, normalize the velocity vector m:

```
m = ccpMult(ccpNormalize(m), kSpeed);
```

kSpeed is a constant float value to adjust the speed.

Hope that helps...

Comment: I updated my question..I'm trying to use idea 3 and it nearly works..are you so kind to help me? I tried idea 1 and it has the same problem and idea 2 doesn't works too. For idea 4: I don't want to use box2d because my game is so simple and box2d is just too much for it...

Comment: Thank you it worked...I'm just curious: How could it be done with box2d? Could you show it me please?